# Bash: Can variable name expansion (${!prefix*}) list all declared variable in script?

Tags: bash

Following the bash manual describing `${!prefix*} ${!prefix@}`

> **Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with prefix**, separated by the >first character of the IFS special variable. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion >appears within double quotes, each variable name expands to a separate word.

Here, my question is "can I use the ${!prefix*} to list all declared variable in script?"

In my example code

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR1="VAR1"
VAR2="VAR2"
NON_VAR="VAR3"

echo "${!VAR*}"
echo "${!*}"
echo "${!^*}"

RESULT======================
VAR1 VAR2
"NOTING_PRINTED"
"NOTING_PRINTED"
```

I've expected it could be used to print all the declared variable

like as it could successfully print all "VAR*" variables, but couldn't.

I know that there are other options that I can choose to list all declared variables, but

I would like to know if it is possible under this syntax.

Comment: Apparently not. I also tried ${![abc]*} and ${![^!]*}. No luck.

Comment: `eval echo '${!'{{a..z},{A..Z},_}'*}'`

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over all the possible first characters of variable names:

```
for ch in {a..z} {A..Z} _ ; do
    eval s='${!'$ch'*}'
    [[ $s ]] && echo $s
done
```

Or just call `set` with no parameters.